# How to prevent inkscape to save svg to pdf with multiple pages?

Tags: inkscape, pdf

I'm using mac OS.
First I saved the svg to pdf. I got a single page pdf which is needed form me.
But later I edited it a bit, added somthing, the convertied pdf became 2 pages.
Does anyone know how to prevent multiple pages, and why this happens?
How can I get a singel page pdf?

[image: First I saved the svg to pdf. I got a single page pdf which is needed form me. But later I edited it a bit, added somthing, the convertied pdf became 2 pages]